# how to pass city name as a parameter to Autocomplete Query

Tags: java, android

I want to search nearby locations... Here is the code for autocomplete suggestions

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE
                    + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
            sb.append("?key=" + API_KEY);
            sb.append("&types=(regions)");
            sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));
```

how can I pass particular city name Or radius as a parameter please help me

Comment: can you give a link to api?

Comment: Yes here it is my link 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key="""MyKey"""&types=(cities)&input=Nalluri+Saraswathamma+Road